# 2 Forms - Combobox + ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to pass the listview ( form1 ) for the combo box ( form2 ) but is not working.

Form2 code:

```
private void add_citacao_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form_Principal frm_prin = new Form_Principal();
    for (int i = frm_prin.listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(frm_prin.listView1.Items[i].Text);
}
```

Form1 code:

```
private void barButtonItem40_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    add_citacao add_cit = new add_citacao();
    add_cit.Show();
}
```

the above code should pass values ​​of the listview which is in the form1 , to a combobox that the form2 .

No error messages;

Comment: The text *"is not working"* does not tell us what is wrong. Please read [mcve] then [edit] the question to add the missing information.

Comment: I think you have it reveresed. You create an NEW instance of your Parent Form in you INNER form. And read it from it. You should create a new instance of your inner form in your outer form and ASSIGN there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Elements such as combos and list boxes should never be passed, what you should do is pass the class that the control is displaying

so if you have a Observable collection or other object that has a event to notify about changed to the collection you can call code on the form to update itself

```
class form1
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList{ get; }= new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public form1()
    {
        MyList.CollectionChanged += onCollectionChanged ;
        form2.MyList = MyList;
        form2.Initialise();
    }

    private void onCollectionChanged (object sender,CollectionChangedEventArg args)
    {
         //update control on form1
    }
    private void AddItemToList(string item)
    {
         MyList.Add(item);
         //this will then raise a CollectionChanged event in both form1 and 2 (and anything else that is listerning to the event) allowing both to automatically add the new item in the control on themselves
    }
}
class form2
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList{ get; set; }
    public void Initialise()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(MyList);
        MyList.CollectionChanged += onCollectionChanged ;//leave out if you don't need this form to monitor changes
    }

    private void onCollectionChanged (object sender,CollectionChangedEventArg args)
    {
         //update control on form2
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge. I started in C # two days ago . I do not need the form1 be updated. I want only the form2 show the values ​​of the listview form1 in a combobox.

Comment: This will still be the way to go, by passing an underlying collection you are separating the User interface from the data, which is good practice anyway

Comment: as an example as your form 2 is only doing show not showdialog then form 1 is still active when form 2 is open, if you follow this proper route then when someone adds a new value on form1 then form 2 is automatically updated to include the new value, otherwise new values would not appear in form 2 until it was closed and reloaded

Comment: This is exact what i want ("otherwise new values would not appear in form 2 until it was closed and reloaded")... i dont need the auto update

inside de OnCollectionChanged, i put the initial code?

for (int i = frm_prin.listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(frm_prin.listView1.Items[i].Text);

Comment: in that case just don't attach the event listener in form 2 and in the initialise command copy MyList to combo `comboBox1.Items.Clear();comboBox1.Items.AddRange(MyList );`

Comment: Got I ... Thank you for your help and patience

Comment: i Tried to implement, but failed... where i put this code?

Comment: updated the answer to include your requested changes